# How best should I interact with Flash from Selenium Java WebDriver

Tags: java, flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am aware a bunch of similar questions such as ([Interact flash elements using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329958/interact-flash-elements-using-webdriver)) have been asked in the past however it is still not clear how best to interact with a Flash Element on a page in association with Selenium's Java WebDriver.

By default I know it doesnt support Flash, so I use it to log onto the site which is fine. Now I need to interact with a flash element as seen on this page :

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/free-tr-4-id/?piid=34979&pbid=517639039

I want to be able to pick a shoe size from the Flash on the left hand side of the page, and then click the add to cart button.

Can anybody who has achieved this please offer their guidance and opinion on the best way. I have tried https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/ however this appears to be old, or not compatible with the new Java WebDriver.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This was a long time ago and no longer need a solution, but the last answer on this page would likely be the kind of solution I would go for if required.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is: No, there is no way you can interact with Flash **from/using** Selenium WebDriver. Full stop.

I know there are heaps of developers out there need to automated Flash. But this has never been a part of the Selenium project and it will never be added into. You might want to have a wander around [Selenium Users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/selenium-users).

For projects like [flash-selenium](https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) and [flex-ui-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/), they are not part of the Selenium project but created by third party, which means they can easily be discontinued due to various reasons. If you have decided to use them, you might end up developing the project itself instead of using it. Furthermore, I'm not aware of such projects compatible with Selenium WebDriver anyway.

One other possible solution might be using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), which is not a Flash automation tool though. It should support automating Flash with its unique image comparison technology. But once again, this has nothing to do with Selenium in any way.

Answer (score -1):

There is a massive misconception that webdriver cannot interact with flash elements.The answer is YES you can interact with flash elements embedded inside html if you can locate the xy coordinates you can interact using selenium ACTION class like so..

```
Actions Action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement e = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button"));
Action.moveToElement(e).clickAndHold().perform();
Action.release().perform();
```