# Get element size using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to check if flash video is minimized or maximized. Tried to do something like this:

```
var video = Program.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//object[contains(@id, 'player_api')]"));

int videoSize = video.Size.Width;

if (videoSize > 1024)
{
     //Do something...
}
```

But I am getting fixed size of HTML element. Any suggestion?

Comment: can you please give us a sample page to check the video. :)

Comment: @AntonAngelov *Thank you for your comment, http://steeles.cream-club.co.uk/ please take a look at the main video on the page at the center of the screen.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you can locate the following element:

```
var video = Program.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='player_api']/param[6]"));
```

Then get its value and then find the video sizes in the flash object. You can even deserialize the value to C# object from the JSON. Check the image: http://screencast.com/t/sYu3DYxo6V

Comment: Thank you, what is going to happen with the parameters when window is maximized? Are they going to change or they are static ?

Comment: You should try but I assume that they should be different. :)

Comment: Is there any possibility to get that maximize button inside of the flash player as an element ?

Comment: I don't think that WebDriver support it natively. However, you can try to automate it with Sikuli- sikuli.org/ + you can check the following article- http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testing-flash-selenium-flash-javascript-communication/

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can find even more detailed information about WebDriver-flash support in the following thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241074/how-best-should-i-interact-with-flash-from-selenium-java-webdriver However, it is the same thing that I have already told you. Good luck!