# Selecting checkbox which is on shockwave flash and does not have any id in html code

Tags: python, flash, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I am working on website where it is a graph of traffic and it has shockwave flash which has some checkboxes after selecting them it performs some operations for example selecting 'subscribed bandwidth' shows bandwidth line on that traffic graph. Problem is there is no element in html code to interact with it.I am using selenium webdriver with python.Below is html code for that

```
<div id="chartContainer">
 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="LineChart" height="830" width="100%">
     <param name="flashVars" value="use_1024=false&amp;dataMultFactor=1000">
     <param name="movie" value="swf/AryakaCharts.swf?version=26128">
     <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
     <param name="quality" value="high">
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7">
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
     <embed src="swf/companyCharts.swf?version=26128"  quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7" 
     name="LineChart" id="LineChart" align="middle" play="true" height="830"  width="100%"   wmode="transparent" flashvars="use_1024=false&amp;dataMultFactor=1000"   loop="false"allowscriptaccess="sameDomain"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution these checkbox uses cookies to store the state so by setting them as true it worked .

Answer (score 1):

***Selenium cannot interact with Flash objects.***

*But you can use **FlashSelenium:***

**URL:** http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/

**Other:**
**1) *Sikuli*:** http://www.sikuli.org/ but it is based on java.
**2) *Adobe's 'Genie' library*:**
**3) *Ranorex's library*:**
**4) *AUTOIT***

As suggested by ***#Martin Swanepoel*** about interacing  with the flash by simulating mouse hold\up, you can do that in JAVA by using or importing java.awt.Robot package (which can be used for real time activity) 
e.g

```
import java.awt.Robot;

Robot robot = new Robot();   

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);      
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);   
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Frankly speaking i am not sure about this one(java.awt.Robot).

Another way is to use Javascript.

***Hope this answer your Question.***

Comment: Thank you but  http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/ it did not work ...........

Comment: i think  javascript don't work because data fetched is once while loading page  after that there is no interaction for that graph even though i select/unselect checkbox it just hides/shows the line

Comment: What do you mean by did not work?? Is it is down or you try it but it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at - [How best should I interact with Flash from Selenium Java WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241074/how-best-should-i-interact-with-flash-from-selenium-java-webdriver)

> The answer to your question is: No, there is no way you can interact
>   with Flash from/using Selenium WebDriver. Full stop.

However another user seemed to have figured out a way to interact with the flash by simulating mouse hold\up. The post is related to Java but you use the same classes to interact in Python.

> There is a massive misconception that webdriver cannot interact with
>   flash elements.The answer is YES you can interact with flash elements
>   embedded inside html